# Can someone explain the kernel\* in this command?

Tags: yum, rhel-6

```
yum list installed kernel\*
```

I don't understand how this would differ from "kernel*", or why the backslash is necessary.

Comment: Hm. Not too sure then. Normally `\*` would mean you search for a literal asterisk and not the wildcard.

Comment: Seems like 
    kernel\*
and
    "kernel*"
give the same results. Perhaps yum passes this parameter to something else, so the * needs to be escaped first.

Answer (score 3):

My guess: to prevent shell glob expansion in case you execute the command in a directory containing some file beginning with "kernel".